# Reduce file cache in java

Tags: java, tomcat, file-io, hash, bufferedreader

I am working on a web service(web project) written in java using the tomcat server. I have written some code for reading the content of the file & create a hash of this file. The file is getting updated daily, I want the hash to to be updated daily too. But this is not happening until I reload the web service explicitly via tomcat server.

Is there any way to reduce the cache time of the hash or should the hash be created freshly irrespective of a external reload command?

This is how i am reading the file:

```
static Map<String, Object> mcatFullDataHash;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mcat_group.tsv"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> mcatInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    line_elements = line.split("\\t");
    mcatInfo.put("groupid",line_elements[2]);
    mcatInfo.put("catid",line_elements[1]);
    mcatInfo.put("no_to_show_mcat", line_elements[4]);
    mcatFullData.put(line_elements[0],mcatInfo);
}
```

mcatFullDataHash is the hash from where I am reading the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start a background thread which checks the file date every now and then and which trigger a reload.

Another option is to use a library like [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which has a [cache implementation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Eviction) that eventually "forgets" about items in the cache.

Note: The Guava cache expects that you can load each element in the cache individually. In your case, you want to expunge the whole cache. A simple way to do that is so the save the `mcatFullDataHash` as a single item in the Guava cache. That way, you can create the inner cache in the `load()` method of the `CacheLoader()` and configure the Guava cache to evict the element after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the file modification time along with the cache and check it every time you go to the cache. If it's out of date, reload.